# C array elements poiting to same location

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

Need some help please. I have the following code.

```
    char *lines[100];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        char temp[10];
        _itoa_s(i, temp,10);
        char result[10] = "test";
        strcat_s(result, temp);

        lines[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
        lines[i] = result;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        cout << lines[i] << endl;
    }
```

Why does it print :

```
test99
test99
test99
...
```

It turns out that `char result[10]` will  point to the
same memory location. Why ? Was expecting something like this :

```
test1
test2
test3
...
```

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: In C, you're using `cout`????

Comment: HInt: why do we pass a size to `malloc()`, at all?

Comment: @SouravGhosh ....or are you using malloc in c++...? ;) malloc cast is required with c+ compiler.

Comment: I come from C# background. I m just interested in C logic and memory management ... not the details ( cout vs printf )

Comment: @doremifasolasido  The program has undefined behavior. For starters the memory is allocated incorrectly for the array elements and the variable result is a local variable that is declared in a code block and is not alive outside it.

Comment: `result` scope is for loop scope. I think it is UB to access its address after the loop.

Comment: @doremifasolasido You do know that C doesn't have `cout`, right? That's a C++ thing. And as for the solution, `lines[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
        lines[i] = result;` → `lines[i] = malloc(strlen(result) + 1);
        strcpy(lines[i], result);`

Comment: @CoolGuy (probable reply :P) why you're bothering, I don't mind whether it's there or not....

Comment: @LPs Using malloc in C++ means something is fundamentally wrong with your program. It is not compatible with classes, nor with `new/delete`.

Comment: @Lundin For sure. I tried tagged the question as C++-no-oop, as the code is, but was rejected. BTW I meant using c++ compiler to compile the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line here is a basically NOOP (actually it is creating a memory leak because you throw away the pointer returned by `malloc` by overwriting it on the next line).

```
lines[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));  // this is a basically a NOOP
lines[i] = result;
```

It's more or less like writing:

```
foo = 5;
foo = result;
```

So your code ends up like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    char temp[10];
    _itoa_s(i, temp,10);
    char result[10] = "test";
    strcat_s(result, temp);

    lines[i] = result;  // copying just the pointer,
}
```

So all `lines[i]` contain the pointer to the same memory location `result`.

Also the scope of `result` is limited to the part between `{}`, so once the `for` loop is terminated, `result` is likely to be overwritten at the next occasion.

You need this:

```
char *lines[100];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    char temp[10];
    _itoa_s(i, temp,10);
    char result[10] = "test";
    strcat_s(result, temp);

    lines[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(result)   + 1);
                                         // ^string length     ^space for NUL terminator

    strcpy(lines[i], result);  // actually copying the the string (not only the pointer)
}
```

You also need to free the allocated memory once you're done with it:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    free(lines[i]);
}
```

Comment: It is not really a no-op, because it has the side-effect of creating a fat memory leak. In the OP's code, the compiler will blindly follow the instructions: "Aha, this line must get executed because the programmer wants a memory leak here". Unlike the code `foo = 5; foo = result;` where the first assignment may get optimized away.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, due to

```
 lines[i] = result;
```

all the pointers end up pointing to the same `result`, the last one.

You may want to use `strcpy()` if you're interested in the *content*.

But wait, there's another problem. You're written

```
 lines[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

which allocates 1 byte of memory, which is here, good for nothing. Before you use the pointer as destination in `strcpy()`, you need to make sure that the pointer points to sufficient memory, including the terminating null, to hold the concatenated *string*.

Advice: The devil is in the *details*. perform a careful study of the language before performing trial and error.

Comment: Doesn't the scope of result matter here? It is UB to access result address after lop scope, isn't it?

Comment: @LPs hah, right of course.... but probably with addition of strcpy(), that will be avoided and that's the target.